# How to refresh OnPaint() function; Window Update is not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

This is my code:

```
void CChildView::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CBitmap b; b.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1);
    CDC memdc; memdc.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
    auto prev = memdc.SelectObject(&b);
    BITMAP bmp; b.GetBitmap(&bmp);

    int bitmap_height = bmp.bmHeight;
    int bitmap_width = bmp.bmWidth;

    if (!painted) {

        nrows = divide(bitmap_height, 8);
        ncols = divide(bitmap_width, 8);

        piece_height = bitmap_height / nrows;
        piece_width = bitmap_width / ncols;

        int number_of_tiles = nrows * ncols;

        positions.resize(number_of_tiles);
        std::iota(positions.begin(), positions.end(), 0);
        empty = positions.size() - 1;//prazna pločica je zadnja
        std::shuffle(positions.begin(), positions.end(), std::mt19937{ std::random_device{}() });

        painted = true;

    }

    

    for (int i = 0; i < positions.size()-1; ++i) {

        int row_dest = positions[i] / ncols;
        int col_dest = positions[i] % ncols;
        int row_src = i / ncols;
        int col_src = i % ncols;

        int x_src = col_src * piece_width;
        int y_src = row_src * piece_height;
        int x_dest = col_dest * piece_width;
        int y_dest = row_dest * piece_height;

        dc.BitBlt(x_dest, y_dest, piece_width, piece_height, &memdc, x_src, y_src, SRCCOPY);
     dc.SelectObject(prev);
    }
}

void CChildView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call def

    CWnd::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);

    //koordinate gdje je korisnik kliknuo

    int row = point.y / piece_height;
    int col = point.x / piece_width;

    int empty_row = empty / ncols;
    int empty_col = empty % ncols;

    bool slide = false;

    switch (abs(row - empty_row)) {
    case 1:
        if (abs(col==empty_col))
            slide = true;
        break;
    case 0:
        if (abs(col-empty_col==1))
            slide = true;
        break;
    }

    if (slide) {
        int old_index = row * ncols + col;
        positions[old_index] = positions[empty];
        empty = old_index;


        CWnd::InvalidateRect(NULL, FALSE);
        CWnd::UpdateWindow();
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a program that is called SlidingPuzzle. I managed to divide a bitmap into rectangles and shuffle them randomly. However, when I click on a rectangle there is no change. I suppose that `UpdateWindow()` is not working. It should refresh `OnPaint()` function. Can someone please help me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. I can assure you that `UpdateWindow()` works. 2. I suggest to cleanup the `OnPaint` function to make it easier to understand and debug. Move the `if (!painted)` block to another function, it doesn't paint anything. Move `b.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1);` there, too - you don't need to load it repeatedly, on every `WM_PAINT`. 3. Why are you doing this `dc.SelectObject(prev);` in a loop?

Comment: You aren't going to learn Windows programming using MFC. This has not ever worked. Learn [Windows API programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows) first. Once you have a *solid* foundation, you can decide whether MFC can make your program easier to write or maintain.

Comment: Maybe `slide` parameter is always false so window is not repainted. Or it's repainted but it's the same canvas. Who knows! You should make a minimum reproducible code, with a simpler example, where all the variable are defined. The bitmap can be loaded once, the memory dc can be reused so you can paint directly without calling invalidate.

Comment: There is definitely a bug, concerning the release-select of the bitmap (although I'm not sure if this is the only reason why your app doesn't work) : The `prev` bitmap was taken out of the `memdc`, not the window DC, so it must be selected back into the mem-dc instead. And not inside that `for` loop, once is enough. There may be other bugs too (with the rectangles, the positions etc - quite complicated to post here and expect debugging without having someone actually downloading it and compiling it on his/her own machine). Oh, and better use the `OnDraw()` member, not the `OnPaint()` one.